# List of tensors and just tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, torch

I am updating codes from tensorflow 1.x to 2.1.0.

I changed tensorflow 1.x code

```
labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int64)
predict = tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1)
tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predict)
```

to tensorflow 2.1.0 code.

```
labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int64)
predict = tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1)
tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy.update_state(labels, predict) #updated code
```

But, when I run the updated code, I got the following error.

```
TypeError: update_state() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_pred'
```

So, I checked the tensorflow 2.1.0 document, and parameters for `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy.update_state()` seem to be a list (in form of [ , , , ]). Then, I searched for a way to convert tensor to a list, which is

```
labels = tf.make_tensor_proto(labels)
labels = tf.make_ndarray(labels)
```

After I run this code, it gives the following error.

```
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

So, I tried to turn a list of Tensors into Tensors with

```
labels = tf.stack(labels)
#or
labels = torch.stack(labels)
```

`tf.stack()` did not work, as it gave the same initial TypeError saying 'y_pred' is missing at the updated code.

`torch.stack()`, however, gave the following error.

```
TypeError: stack() : argument 'tensors' (position 1) must be tuple of Tensors, not Tensor
```

So, I am guessing `torch.stack()` only accepts a tuple, **NOT a list**.
But, `tf.stack()` seems to accept a list, but it does not turn it into a Tensor?

Are my labels and predict even a list of Tensors in the first place? If so, why would tf.stack() not turn them into Tensors? How can I correctly convert labels and predict so that they can be passed into `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy.update_state()`?

I would very much appreciate if not using `compat.v1.` unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in this way:

```
labels = [0,1]
logits = np.asarray([[0.9,0.1],[0.1,0.9]])

labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int64)
predict = tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1)
acc = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
acc = acc.update_state(y_true=labels, y_pred=predict)
acc
```

Comment: Above code does not give any errors, but when I run ```acc```, it gives the following result: ```<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=2.0>```

Comment: Actually, your code helped! In my original code, I forgot to add () after ```tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy```. Thanks!

Comment: Great! don't forget to upvote and accept it as answer

Comment: Quick question tho. Like I said in the earlier comment, if I run your code, acc gives ```<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=2.0>```. But, in my original code, if I run the same code, it gives ```<tf.Variable 'AssignAddVariableOp_1' shape=() dtype=float32>```. And I can't get ```acc.result().numpy()``` in my original code. Do you know why there is a difference in acc?

Comment: In your original code you are updating nothing... you have to initialize the acc method and then update then calling when it's necessary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213910/discussion-between-beginnercoder-and-marco-cerliani).